# Access VBA API cannot access files on Windows 8

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

### Solution:  Turns out this win 8 machine was hiding known file extensions.  Both of my test files ended up being testing.txt.txt and testing.pdf.pdf which of course would fail when I tried to find testing.txt.

For some reason any part of the VBA api that does file operations fails on my system running windows 8, but succeeds on windows 7 (both running Access 2013).

I was trying to use the FollowHyperlink method as a simple way to open a .pdf file.  So I started simple:

FollowHyperlink "C:\TestingFolder" - Yields an explorer window opened to the path (great!)
FollowHyperlink "C:\TestingFolder\foo.pdf" - Yields Error 490 Cannot open the specified file

So then I tried the Filelen function and got another error that it could not access the file.

I ended up at the conclusion that any operation that actually accessed a file would fail, likely due to some security setting.  The fact it works on Windows 7 and not 8 seems to indicate that something at the OS level may be at fault.

Resolutions I tried:

- Ran Access explicitly as administrator
- Moved files into user directories and out of root
- Went into the Access Trust Center and disabled all security measures (temporarily)
- Tried different file types (.pdf, .txt)

Comment: and using this exact same command from a CMD window is successfully?

Comment: @Brad I'll have to try this evening to be sure, but I know the path was good.  The exact same code actually worked when I ran it on Win 7.

Comment: I'd wonder if you have permission to open the file, too

Comment: @Brad Yeah, I wonder that myself (this has been a perplexing problem)

Comment: is this on the same computer? Win8/Win7? Where are you getting the path from? Explorer? Can you verify the permissions on the folder and file?

Comment: @Brad Different machines, sadly neither in front of me at the moment.  I got the paths from explorer.  Permissions should have been adequate, I tried both off root C and from the user's "Documents" directory.  I was able to use the VBA MkDir method to create folders in the same directories as the files I was attempting to read.

Comment: @Brad Found the error.... turns out this win 8 machine was hiding known file extensions.  Both of my test files ended up being testing.txt.txt and testing.pdf.pdf... so visually they looked right but big surprise that nothing could find testing.txt :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this win 8 machine was hiding known file extensions. Both of my test files ended up being testing.txt.txt and testing.pdf.pdf which of course would fail when I tried to find testing.txt.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not the Windows API, but the installation of the software. The FollowHyperlink, uses the system registry where the file type association is involved. If PDF files are associated with Adobe Reader and you have it installed and made PDF to be, by default open with Adobe then you will not have a problem. However if your system lacks the program that could open a file with a "creepy" extension then it will fail miserably.

Your solution is to find the appropriate program to open the file. Then use the code, it will open the appropriate file with its associated program.

Comment: I tried multiple paths to opening the file including the shell API.
It also fails with txt files or any other extension.  Lastly, even the FileLen method fails and it should operate on any file.

Comment: @Sparkfizt, have you give Allen Browne's GoHyperlink method a go? http://allenbrowne.com/func-GoHyperlink.html